# Android onClickListener issues

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm struggling to understand how to implement OnClickListeners.

Below is the code for one of the pages I'm putting together. Now it has 2 buttons. Button 3 needs to go to one page and then button 4 needs to go to another page. I have added the information for button 3 to tell it where it needs to go, but it doesn't seem to like it. I'm also unsure how to connect button 4 to "com.example.sjmplanningfinal.GPDOClassB2nd" and where to copy from, if that makes sense?

And also what I have done incorrectly on the code below.

```
package com.example.sjmplanningfinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener

public class GPDOClassB1st extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gpdoclass_b1st);

    Button btnSimple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
    btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                    com.example."com.example.sjmplanningfinal.GPDOClassB1stFail");
            startActivity(intent1);

                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Intent`, use `current` activity `GPDOClassB1st` as `first` parameter and `GPDOClassB1stFail` as `second` parameter.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

**Update `onClick()` method as below:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(GPDOClassB1st.this, GPDOClassB1stFail.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a go in the morning.